# Chainable python shell script, can be used multiple times

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix

I'd like to create a python shell script `myscript.py` that can feed output to a pipe or receive input to a pipe, *more than once*. eg.

`$ myscript.py | myscript.py | myscript.py ...`

The implementation below only works to a limited extent:

```
$ myscript.py
NO INPUT
(ok)

$ echo 'hello' | myscript.py
GOT INPUT >>> hello
(ok)


$ myscript.py | myscript.py
NO INPUT

(not ok, should be)
NO INPUT
GOT INPUT >>> NO INPUT
```

Here is the contents of myscript.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys,os
    if (os.fstat(sys.stdin.fileno()).st_size > 0):
        stdincontents=sys.stdin.read()
        print "GOT INPUT >>> " + stdincontents
    else:
        print "NO INPUT"
```

Comment: I think there is a fundamental problem: the script either has to _block_ waiting for input, or terminate because there was no input.  The way you've described it, you want the first process in the chain to write "NO INPUT" and terminate - but you want the other processes later on in the chain to block and wait.  But since they are all the same program they have the same behaviour, some of the processes later on in the chain will also die saying no input and terminate, closing the pipe.  So I don't understand how it can ever work.

Comment: No blocking. I just needed a way to decompose my new python software system into modular elements, and I wanted to mimic pipe-able shell processes. To keep the architecture simple. The answer from @thatotherguy was just what I needed. In his example he adds a prompt when there is no input, probably to illustrate the test to check if there is input or not. Since I don't want any blocking, I will simply replaced this with `if (os.isatty(0)): <alternative input, like command line arguments etc>`. I'm not sure how I accidentally gave the impression I wanted blocking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to find the size of the file on stdin, but stdin is not a file so it fails.

Instead, just read and see whether you get something:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys,os
    if (os.isatty(0)):
        print("This program reads from stdin, which is currently a terminal.\n" +
              "Please type some text and finish with Ctrl+D.\n" +
              "(This informative text is not passed on.)", file=sys.stderr);

    stdincontents=sys.stdin.read()
    if(len(stdincontents) > 0):
        print("GOT INPUT >>> " + stdincontents)
    else:
        print("NO INPUT")
```

Rather than doing what you want it to do, this program uses standard UNIX semantics:

1. You say you want your second example to print `NO OUTPUT` and then `GOT INPUT >>> NO OUTPUT`. This is not normal: `echo foo | nl | rev` will not print `1 foo` followed by `oof 1`.

   If you want to look at output from an arbitrary point in a pipeline as well as the final output, use

   `echo foo | nl | tee /dev/stderr | rev`
2. When run directly by the user, programs are expected to read from stdin, not to give up and run without input.

   This program prints an informational message on how to do that. If you feel strongly that Unix is wrong, you can switch it around to just not read input instead.

Here's how it works:

```
$ echo hello | ./myscript.py
GOT INPUT >>> hello

$ echo hello | ./myscript.py | ./myscript.py
GOT INPUT >>> GOT INPUT >>> hello

$ ./myscript.py | ./myscript.py 
This program reads from stdin, which is currently a terminal.
Please type some text and finish with Ctrl+D
(This informative text is not passed on.)
***pressed ctrl+d here***
GOT INPUT >>> NO INPUT
```